# VB 2012 Can't see codes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I just installed **VB 2012**. So I can see form design but when I double click on my class or any other component *(button, textbox, progressbar...)* I get only **blank code window**. I tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2012 but I got same problem again.
Anyone know what is problem or it's just bug.

Comment: So your problem is that it does not generate a default handler for you? Or, that it does not navigate to the default handler when you click on the control? Or, that the class window is completely empty, not even Class Form1 (or whatever)...End Class? A screenshot would certainly help.

Comment: If I remember correctly, that's how WinForms is for VB.Net. If you check the "Show All Files" icon in your solution explorer, you should see that there is also a designer file. If you want to fire something up when the form opens, just double click on the blank form in your designer, it throw a page load event in your main form's vb file.